# Can you make permissions expire after a certain date?

Tags: 2013, permissions

I'm providing some users temporary access to an area for end of financial year and I want to make those permissions expire in two weeks. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well everything is possible, but this is not OTB functionality in SharePoint. It will need custom development, and quite a lot of it. Perhaps creating AD accounts just for this purpose, with expiring passwords is a better strategy?

Comment: I had thought of that - but it's existing roles gaining increased functionality whilst a team leader is on leave. I suppose I'll write something custom - was just hoping I could avoid that, dependencies and all that jazz!

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat simple approach is to utilize PowerShell and Task Scheduler.

1. For a one off, you can simply schedule the task to run on a specific
   date/time and run script to remove rights from the user.
2. You could expand it by using a tracking list that holds user and
   expire date, then have the script check this and run based on the
   inputs.

Have the scheduler run something like this (just a sample, you can expand as needed of course):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <your url>
$user = get-spuser -Identity <username> -Web $web.url
$list = $web.Lists[<libaryname>]
$list.RoleAssignments.Remove( $user )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the licensed versions, this can be accomplished using the Records Management feature. It is more about declaring the item as a record based on some criteria, and executing the records management rule that would cause that permissions on the item to be effected.

Comment: But would this not be item based, rather than Web or List based? I mean, can you use it for setting List or Web permissions rather than item permissions?